# Copy all files in hadoop directory except 1

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop, hdfs

I am writing a shell script to put all my files in hadoop directory.

I used the command:

```
hadoop dfs -put /opt/nikoo28/resources/conf ./
```

Now this copies the folder conf in my hadoop home directory overwriting everything.

However, there is one file, **"doNotCopy.txt"** which I do not want to copy. Is there some method by which I can skip a particular file?

Comment: You can just delete that file after copying: `rm ./conf/doNotCopy.txt`

Comment: actually my hadoop dfs already contains a doNotCopy.txt I do not want to overwrite it. Think of it as a user configuration file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add these lines in your shell script:**

```
mkdir /opt/copy
mv /opt/nikoo28/doNotCopy.txt /opt/copy/doNotCopy.txt
hadoop dfs -put /opt/nikoo28/resources/conf ./ && mv /opt/copy/doNotCopy.txt /opt/nikoo28/doNotCopy.txt
```

Just move the file you don't want to copy to some other folder. Perform **hadoop fs -put** command. Now, move back the file to its original position.

**If you want to preserve file permissions, then do this:**

```
mkdir /opt/copy
cp -p /opt/nikoo28/doNotCopy.txt /opt/copy/doNotCopy.txt
rm /opt/nikoo28/doNotCopy.txt
hadoop dfs -put /opt/nikoo28/resources/conf ./ && cp -p /opt/copy/doNotCopy.txt /opt/nikoo28/doNotCopy.txt
```

> **NOTE:** Add **sudo** if you get permission errors while creating directory, moving the file or copying the file.

Comment: do i assume superuser privileges?

Comment: If you don't have superuser privilege, then you can move or copy the file where you have permission. You can skip `sudo` in shell script.

Comment: So basically you are just doing a backup of the original file and placing it again

Answer (score 1):

I see in [Apache Hadoop docs #put](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put):

> Usage: hadoop fs -put  ...
>
> Copy single src, or multiple srcs from local file system to the
>   destination file system. Also reads input from stdin and writes to
>   destination file system.

And then a useful example

> hadoop fs -put - hdfs://nn.example.com/hadoop/hadoopfile Reads the
>   input from stdin.

So maybe you can use a `find` expression grepping this file out and then pipe to `hadoop`:

```
find /opt/nikoo28/resources/conf ! -name "doNotCopy.txt" | hadoop dfs -put - ./
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda peculiar, but should work:

```
file=./conf/doNotCopy.txt
[[ -f $file ]] && mv $file $file.old
hadoop dfs -put /opt/nikoo28/resources/conf ./
rm $file
[[ -f $file ]] && mv $file.old $file
```